# Calculator to return current year plus one

Tags: calculations, date-calculations

I am trying to use the package calculator to return current year plus one. I have tried the following but it does not seem to work. Any suggestions?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{calculator}

\begin{document}

\COPY{\the\year{}}{\numberYYYY}
\numberYYYY

\ADD{\numberYYYY}{1}{\yearPlus} \yearPlus

\end{document}
```

Instead of 2022 it returns =12021 and an error message "Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)".
Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't redefine `\=`, that's a macro used by LaTeX.

Comment: you dont need `{}` after `\the\year{}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No idea on how to do this in `calculator`, but you can do the following to let a macro to the result of your calculation:

```
\newcommand*\myresult{} % check whether the macro is available
\edef\myresult{\the\numexpr\year+1\relax}
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually the only thing I need is the {\number\numexpr\year+1\relax} it works like a charm.